# how to resolve htmlUnit WrapsDriver Error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

I'm running test with HtmlUnit with selenium 3.13 jar, browser launches successfully, but after than it stops working with below error.

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WrapsDriver
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.toWebElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementByName(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1341)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:284)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$4.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:2024)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$4.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:2020)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1660)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:2020)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:798)
    at com.directlegalmail.startup.Startup.scrapDates(Startup.java:89)
    at com.directlegalmail.startup.Startup.main(Startup.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WrapsDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
```

does anyone knows how to resolve it, I have 
selenium 3.13
and htmlUnit Driver 2.33

below is my code

```
driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait
(10000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
logMsg("Browser launched successfully");
driver.get("WebURL");
```

Comment: any reason to use htmlunit driver ? instead use chrome or Firefox headless mode

Comment: it is much more faster than others

Comment: And how do you predict that ? https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/31233/how-headless-mode-is-faster

Comment: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#htmlunit-driver  see the Pros written in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use htmlUnit Driver with dependencies, download the latest [htmlunit-driver-x.xx.x-jar-with-dependencies.jar](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/releases) from github which include `WrapsDriver` class.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information about your *Test Environment* would have given us some more idea what exactly going wrong.

However I don't see any major issues in your code block. With *Selenium v3.14* and *HtmlunitDriver v2.33.0* while invoking *HtmlUnitDriver* you need to pass the argument **true** to enable **JavaScript** and you can use the following solution:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class A_HtmlunitDriver_2_33_0 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53812207/how-to-resolve-htmlunit-wrapsdriver-error");
    System.out.println("HtmlUnitDriver invoked");
    driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This combination of dependencies worked for me:

```
implementation("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59")
implementation("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:3.141.59")
implementation("org.seleniumhq.selenium:htmlunit-driver:2.36.0")
```

You can see the compatible Selenium dependencies for HtmlUnit Driver version `2.36.0` here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/blob/2.36.0/pom.xml