# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking getOffsetTop with HtmlUnitDriver & Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, htmlunit-driver

Whenever I try to set HtmlUnit enableJavaScript to true, it returns this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking getOffsetTop
```

I set it to true with this:

```
driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
```

Before setting enableJavaScript(true), I was receiving an error with this specific line of code:

```
WebElement checkoutEmail = driver.findElement(By.id("checkout_email"));
javascriptExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].value='abc@gmail.com';", checkoutEmail);
```

Previous error message:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Javascript is not enabled for this HtmlUnitDriver instance
```

So basically, after setting it to true, I receive another brand new error.
**Update**
I fixed this by adding this:

```
public class CustomHtmlUnitDriver extends HtmlUnitDriver {


    @Override
    protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {
        WebClient modifiedClient = super.modifyWebClient(client);
        modifiedClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);}}
```

And then I added `((CustomHtmlUnitDriver) driver).setJavascriptEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking getOffsetTop
```

...implies that your program encountered *ScriptException* exception.

Some more information about the version of the binaries you are using would have helped us to debug the root cause in a better way in terms of:

- *Selenium*
- *HtmlUnitDriver*

However, you can use the below mentioned configuration and solution:

- Configuration:

  - *Selenium*: **3.14.0**
  - *HtmlUnitDriver*: **2.33.0**
- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;


  public class A_HtmlunitDriver_2_33_0 {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

      WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53812207/how-to-resolve-htmlunit-wrapsdriver-error");
      System.out.println("HtmlUnitDriver invoked");
      driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  HtmlUnitDriver invoked
  19:10:32.092 [main] DEBUG com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebWindowImpl - destroyChildren
  19:10:32.093 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection manager is shutting down
  19:10:32.094 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-1: Close connection
  19:10:32.095 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
  19:10:32.096 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection manager shut down
  ```

Comment: Still receiving "getOffsetTop" when trying setting enableJavaScript(true)

Comment: In _HtmlUnitDriver: 2.33.0_ `enableJavaScript(true)` is configured by default. The tweaks to default configuration are done in a different way. Can you just copy/paste and test the code and update me accordingly please?